# What is the rigorous difference between accelerations and "felt" accelerations?

Tags: forces, reference-frames, acceleration

(I appologise in advance if the question seems basic, I just never had a lecture on it)

Acceleration is derivative of velocity inside a referential.

Some accelerations aren't felt by the object, but detected through other referencial frames. Such as an apple falling, it doesn't feel the gravitational acceleration. But on the groud, it feels it, even if both the weight force and ground reaction force are acting upon it and canceling.

I would just like to understand the rigorous explanation that separates the felt accelerations, and non felt ones.
I guess it has to do with fictitious forces and non inertial reference frames, but I'd like a rigorous answer.

(The phenomenon that made me question that, is the surface of water, curving (or not) depending on the forces acting upon it. What I noticed (but never saw anywhere), is that its surface is always perpendicular to the direction of the global acceleration it is feeling. If we put it in a rotating container, it feels the gravitationnal acceleration and the centrifugal one, so curves in a parabolic shape, but the forces applying on water by the container (holding the water) don't seem to influence the shape of water's surface.)

Comment: You are actually asking about two different topics: acceleration/forces in general and what happens in the case of a rotating fluid with a free surface. Bothe questions are interesting, but it would be better to ask as two separate questions.

Comment: I think you are conflating _coordinate acceleration_ with _proper acceleration._ https://www.google.com/search?q=%22coordinate+acceleration%22+%22proper+acceleration%22

Answer (score 0):

In physics there are two distinct concepts of acceleration.

> Acceleration is derivative of velocity inside a referential.

This is called "coordinate acceleration". This concept of acceleration depends on the choice of coordinate system. Because you can rather arbitrarily choose your coordinate system you can arbitrarily alter the coordinate acceleration. This means that, without changing anything physical, you can change, introduce, or eliminate coordinate acceleration as desired. Doing so will not affect any measured result.

> But on the ground, it feels [acceleration], even if both the weight force and ground reaction force are acting upon it and canceling.

This is called "proper acceleration". This concept of acceleration is the acceleration that is measured by an accelerometer. This is invariant, it is the same in all coordinate systems because all coordinate systems must agree on the reading of the accelerometer. This is a physical acceleration and cannot be removed or changed by choice of coordinate system. All measurable outcomes depend only on the proper acceleration and not on the coordinate acceleration.

> I would just like to understand the rigorous explanation that separates the felt accelerations, and non felt ones. I guess it has to do with fictitious forces and non inertial reference frames, but I'd like a rigorous answer.

You are correct. Proper acceleration is caused by real forces, which are interactions between things. Coordinate acceleration is "caused" by fictitious forces, which are not interactions but rather they describe how much the coordinate system deviates from an inertial coordinate system.

Be aware, gravity is locally a fictitious force in this sense. Real gravity is effects like tidal forces, which are modeled by spacetime curvature and which vanish to first order (the equivalence principle).

Comment: But in that case, is the centriFUGAL acceleration proper or coordinate? Because from a rotating frame, it is detectable, yet from a fictitious force.

Comment: @PierreCarlier the centrifugal force is a coordinate acceleration. It is not felt. If you place an accelerometer in a centrifuge, the actual measured acceleration is the real centripetal acceleration. The centrifugal acceleration is a fictitious coordinate acceleration and does not affect the outcome of any measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Classically, gravity is a force. In free fall, every atom of your body is pulled down with the same acceleration. You are calling this acceleration. No atom gets ahead of any other. This is just like floating in space. You don't feel anything as you go faster and faster.

If you stand on a scale, the scale pushes up on your feet, keeping you from free fall. Your feel push on your ankles, and so forth. Each part of your body needs to exert an upward force on the next to keep them traveling at the same speed.

Suppose you are in a rocket in space far from Earth. The rocket pushes on your feet, your feet push on your ankles, ... It is just like being in gravity. A scale would show a weight. This is what you are calling a "felt acceleration."

---

Floating in space or in free fall, regard yourself as at rest. Things around you stay at rest without forces to hold them there.

You can regard yourself at rest in free fall too. Things around you stay at rest along with you, with no force to hold them there. Even though your idea of at rest looks like a constantly changing speed to us on the ground, it is very much like floating in space. Einstein could not think of any experiment he could do in a falling elevator that would get a different result from an elevator in space. This is the foundation of general relativity. In GR, free fall is an inertial frame of reference, just like floating in space.

In your view, there is no gravity. We on the ground are accelerating upwards. You see us thinking we are at rest, ignoring this upward acceleration. To stay at rest, we need the ground to push us upward. But if we are at rest, the total force on us must be $0$. There must be a force that pulls everything downward to make the total come out right. This force is gravity. This is why in GR, gravity is called a fictitious force.

So the difference between a acceleration and "felt acceleration" is not a trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

"Felt acceleration" is any acceleration you can detect by feeling it.

Cheeky, I know, but its a useful definition because it points us in the direction of measurement.  Feeling is a measurement.  What you're digging at is how various accelerations can be measured, and by what means.  Take a skydiver who is still accelerating (has not reached terminal velocity).  When you are skydiving, it is *very* obvious that the ground is approaching.  With a little math, you could even compare the angles to various objects on the ground to measure your acceleration.  So that would be an acceleration detected by optical measurements.  If you had an altimeter on your wrist (and you should, given that you are skydiving), its needle moves in response to changing air pressures.  So you could have an acceleration measured by pressure.

So what would be an acceleration that is "felt?"  Feeling is a measurement by stress/strain sensors - structures in your body that are designed to detect when one part of the body (e.g. a tendon) has to exert a force on another body to keep then together.  These structures stretch a little, and you measure that.

Usually you feel gravity because the solid ground underneath you pushes back against your body, stretching and compressing those sensory structures in your body to give you the feeling of weight.  And this is distributed: your legs feel more of it because they support a larger portion of it.  Your head feels less because there's less mass above it, thus keeping the head "in place" against the force of gravity takes less force than it takes to keep your whole torso above your hips.

Go skydiving, and this shifts.  Suddenly there's no ground pushing back up on you, and all parts of your body are being accelerated down at the same rate.  You don't feel this acceleration because there's no stresses being placed on those sensors.

Eventually, as you fall further, gaining velocity (because you're accelerating), you get to terminal velocity, the fastest you can go because the force of drag equals the force of gravity (technically you approach terminal velocity, but that's a minor detail).  Once you're at (or near) terminal velocity, you feel the acceleration of gravity again.  The force of drag is pushing up on the skin on the bottom of your body, and gravity is pulling you down in a distributed manner.  This compresses those stress/strain sensors in your body, as the various parts of your body begin to transmit forces to keep your body together in one piece.

We say water "feels" a force in a rather anthropomorphic sense.  The motion of water is dependent on the relative difference between forces between water molecules.  To say water "feels" gravity or a centripetal acceleration is really just saying that there are relative forces between water molecules that lead the water to form a given surface shape.  We say "feels" in English because its close enough to how our own sense of feeling works to get away with such colloquial English tricks.  More precisely, there's just a difference in relative forces between the water molecules that leads it to move to a given steady-state shape.

When you get to relativity, you'll find that gravity gets special treatment when it comes to the idea of "feeling acceleration."  Relativity deals with some peculiarities of how light and time behave that lead to gravity being unique (to the point of some YouTube stars loudly proclaiming [Gravity is not a Force](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU)).  In the simpler world of Newtonian physics (which is what you are learning now), it gets no special treatment - it's just a force like any other force, felt or unfelt depending on the circumstances.

Comment: I would say that a "felt" acceleration would be one detected by an accelerometer. Like, a system composed of a mass, attached to 3 springs in the x, y and z axis (we don't care about the orientation), and a "felt" force would push the mass away from the center (or equilibrium position). In that case, centriFUGAL acceleration is felt, not centriPETAL. Gravity (on the ground) would be felt, not freefall. Etc...Idk if I'm being clear...